# Convert usize to i16, i32

Tags: rust

> I must say, I'm new to the Rust language, just started learning it.

Look at the code below:

`let center_index_array: i16 = i16::from(nums.len()).div_ceil(2);`

```
pub fn two_sum(mut nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    nums.sort();
    

    let mut empty_vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    let center_index_array: i16 = i16::from(nums.len()).div_ceil(2);

    println!("{}",center_index_array);
    
    for i in nums {
        println!("{}", i * 2);
    }

    return vec![1,2]
}

fn main() {
    two_sum([2,7,11,15].to_vec(), 9);
}
```

I am wondering, what should i do to convert `usize` that i got from length of vector (`len`)?

In typescript, I would get a length as number of array and then use `.ceil()` method to find a center of array. But here I am stuck.

**There is an issue:**

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i16: From<usize>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:45
  |
8 |     let center_index_array: i16 = i16::from(nums.len()).div_ceil(2);
  |                                   --------- ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<usize>` is not implemented for `i16`
  |                                   |
  |                                   required by a bound introduced by this call
  |
  = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
            <i16 as From<bool>>
            <i16 as From<i8>>
            <i16 as From<u8>>
            <i16 as From<NonZeroI16>>

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'int_roundings'
 --> src/main.rs:8:57
  |
8 |     let center_index_array: i16 = i16::from(nums.len()).div_ceil(2);
  |                                                         ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #88581 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/88581> for more information

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0658.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Why are you using `i16`?